# What is the type of result? Is it possible?

Tags: c, gcc, types, type-conversion

I try to search an answer to my question...
What is the type of this expression will be at C language?

```
unsigned short a, b;
a = 0x1;
b = 0x2;
if((a ^ b) > 0) //This expression... 
...
```

I understand that this is not a completely correct code that can cause an error. I should use != instead >.

I think that the type of the result of the expression will be unsigned int. I read about it in Stephen Pratt’s book.

If we have two types, then the result of an expression involving these types must be a superior type. (int or unsigned int)

If these two variables have any other values, can it be that this expression will be less than zero? 
(If we set the most significant bit in the number, it will become negative, provided that it has signed data type)

I think it is impossible, but I could be wrong.
I made my guess, but I want to know the correct answer to my question.

Comment: Unless `INT_MAX` is smaller than `USHORT_MAX`, the expression will be of type `int`. Hence, to have a [mre], you need to post the relevant values from `limits.h`.

Comment: Result of XOR can't be more than 0xFFFF. Thanks.

Comment: How do you figure that out?

Comment: Maximum value of unsigned short can be only 0xFFFF. If we have a equals 0xFFFF and b equals 0, then result of XOR will be 0xFFFF. 16 bit data type...

Comment: The maximum value an `unsigned short` can hold is not `0xFFFF`, it's `USHRT_MAX`, which has an implementation defined value no smaller than `65535`. Consequently, the value can be larger. Moreover, the value of `INT_MAX` is also implementation defined and may be as low as `32767`.

Comment: Consequently, the result depends on the compiler implementation, right?

Comment: Which expression are you asking about, `a ^ b`, `(a ^ b)`, `(a ^ b) > 0`, or something else?

Comment: (a^b). I wondered if it could happen that the result of this expression would be a negative number. in this case, the result of the expression ((a^b) > 0) will be a false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `a ^ b` likely has type `int`, but will have type `unsigned int` in the event that there are any values that can be represented as `unsigned short`s but not as `int`s.  Its value will not exceed `USHRT_MAX` for general `a` and `b` of type `unsigned short`, and will be exactly 3 for the specific `a` and `b` in the example.

(From comments:)

> I wondered if it could happen that the result of [`(a^b)`] would be a negative number. in this case, the result of the expression ((a^b) > 0) will be a false

It will never evaluate to a negative number because whether the usual arithmetic promotions result in the operands being converted to `int` or to `unsigned int`, the resulting values will be unchanged, and therefore non-negative.  Neither operand's sign bit, if any, will be set, so the result's sign bit, if any, will not be set either.

The expression `(a ^ b) > 0` has type `int`, and it evaluates to 1 for the given `a` and `b`.  More generally, it evaluates to the same result as `a != b` for `a` and `b` of integer type.  Of course, that *can* evaluate to 0.  On the other hand, the related expression `(a ^ b) >= 0` will always evaluate to 1 for `a` and `b` of unsigned type.

Answer (score 2):

In `(a ^ b) > 0`, where `a` and `b` are `unsigned short`:

- If `unsigned short` is narrower than `int`, `a` and `b` are each converted to `int` (per the *integer promotions*, C 2018 6.3.1.1 2, and because `unsigned short` being narrower than `int` necessarily means `int` can represent all values of `unsigned short`).
- Otherwise, `a` and `b` are converted to `unsigned int` (*ibid*).
- For `a ^ b`, the *usual arithmetic conversions* are performed (6.5.11). In this expression, the usual arithmetic conversions do not change the types (6.3.1.8 1). Also per the usual arithmetic conversions, the result has the same type as the operands after the conversions. Thus, the result is `int` or `unsigned int` as described above.
- `(a ^ b)` has the same type as `a ^ b` (6.5.1 5).
- For `(a ^ b) > 0`, the result has type `int` (6.5.8 6).